# Dynamic Linq Group By Count

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

**SQL**

```
 select Country,Count(City) as City from Customers group by Country
```

**Controller**
    sortable_top=Country,City

```
     public ActionResult _Query(List<string> sortable_bot, List<string> sortable_top)
    {
        IQueryable result;
        List<M_Customers> result2;
        string gro = string.Join(",", sortable_top);         
        using (var context = new NwContext())
        {
            result = context.Customers;
            result = result.GroupBy("new (" + gro + ")", "it");
            result2 = result.Select<M_Customers>("new (it.Key as Key , Count(City) as Count)").ToList();
        }
        return PartialView(result2);
    }
```

I want to transform a SQL query like this into linq. I'm getting an error message.

```
 result2 = result.Select<M_Customers>("new (it.Key as Key , it.Count() as Count)").ToList();
```

If I write like this I am getting group by count but I dont want this. 
I want the number of grouped cities

Comment: As a suggestion: please do not add code or error messages as images..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result2 = result.Select<M_Customers>("new (it.Key as Key , it.Select(City).Count() as Count)").ToList();
```

I fixed like this

Answer (score 0):

Do it like:

```
"new (it.Key as Key , Count(City != null) as Count)"
```

Because in the end `COUNT(something)` in SQL means something like `SUM(CASE WHEN something IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`. Note that there is no support for `COUNT DISTINCT`!

Comment: I want to get data but it does not provide.

Comment: @DenizOzogul Works on my PC (using SQL Server).

Comment: I do get Key data but not get count

Comment: @DenizOzogul Begin by transforming your query in a non-dynamic linq query and work from there. `context.Customers.GroupBy(x => x.Country).Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Count(y => y.City != null) }).ToList()`

Comment: I cant do this, because I am getting column name dynamic and they changeable

Comment: @DenizOzogul But you have to make it work for a single test case, and then extend the test case. So you need to have two "fixed" query (one in dynamic linq and one in non-dynamic linq) and see if both return the same result. If they work then you know that the problem is somewhere else.